# Show both Screen Sharing and Camera Feed in Agora Video Call Sdk

Tags: android, agora.io, screensharing, videocall, agora

I am using Agora Video call Sdk 4.3.0. I am able to successfully share my screen but sharing my screen stops sharing my camera feed. I want receiver to see my camera feed and my shared screen both.

I am using following method to share the screen

```
 val result = rtcEngine.startScreenCapture(screenCaptureOptions)
```

At receiver's end in OnUserJoined callback I have following code

```
 rtcEngine.apply {
        setupRemoteVideo(VideoCanvas(remoteFeedSurfaceView, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid))
        setRemoteSubscribeFallbackOption(Constants.STREAM_FALLBACK_OPTION_VIDEO_STREAM_LOW)
    }
```

Screen share is working fine. I am able to see the shared screen at receiver end.

I want receiver to see both my Shared Screen and My Camera video.

Moreover, I also want to notify everyone in call and person joining later that I am sharing the screen so that they can show the shared screen in big window and rest in small window or recycler view.

Comment: Can you share the code you have in place?